# StretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth stretching wrong portions

Tags: iphone, uiimage, stretching

I am trying to use a UIImage with stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth to set the image in my UIImageView but am encountering a strange scaling bug. Basically picture my image as an oval that is 31 pixels wide. The left and right 15 pixels are the caps and the middle single pixel is the scaled portion.

This works fine if I set the left cap to 15. However, if I set it to, say, 4. I would expect to get a 'center' portion that is a bit curved as it spans the center while the ends are a little pinched.

What I get is the left cap seemingly correct, followed by a long middle portion that is as if I scaled the single pixel at pixel 5, then a portion at the right of the image where it expands and closes over a width about twice the width of the original image. The resulting image is like a thermometer bulb.

Has anyone seen odd behavior like this and might know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct, Joey. StretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth does NOT expand the whole center of the image as you would expect. It only expands the pixel column just right of the left cap and the pixel row just below the top cap!

Use UIView's contentStretch property instead, and your problem will be solved. Another advantage to this is that contentStretch can also shrink a graphic properly, whereas stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth only works when making the graphic larger.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you right, but LeftCapWidth etc is made for rounded corners, with everything in the rectangle within the rounding radius is stretched to fit the space between the 'caps' on the destination button or such.

So if your oval is taller or wider than 4 x 2 = 8, whatever is in the middle rectangle will be stretched. And yours is, so it would at least look at bit ugly! But if it's not even symmetrical, something has affected the stretch. Maybe something to do with origin or frame, or when it's set, or maybe it's set twice, or you have two different stretched images on top of each other giving the thermometer look.

I once created two identical buttons in the same place, using the same retained object - of course throwing away the previous button. Then I wondered why the heck the button didn't disappear when I set alpha to 0... But it did, it's just that there was a 'dead' identical button beneath it :)